# Change my sidebar menu into button for mobile view and smaller screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

So i'm new to bootstrap.and i was trying out to change my sidebar into a button when screen size is small.

This is a little what i need. I can tweak around a little bit to make it work for my needs except for one. There is a sidebar with links. That sidebar disapears when you make you screen smaller (as would have happened on mobile devices). I want to make sure that the sidebar disapears but have it back with a button.

Here is my code.
HTML and CSS i am using :

```css
#side-bar {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333f4d;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #d7d9db;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
}

#top-bar {
  background-color: #1f2730;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#top-bar:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.sidebarclr {
  background-color: #fafafa !important;
  margin-left: -14px;
}
#logo{
 margin-left: 35px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}
li img{
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.list{
   text-decoration:none!important;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
       padding: 10px;

   }
#sidebl > li a{
 color:#d7d9db !important;
 
}
   
#sidebl >li a:hover{
  background-color:#aaa !important;
  text-decoration:none !important;
 }
 #sidebl >li a:focus{
  background-color:#aaa !important;
  text-decoration:none !important;
 }
#user{
     margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
 
}
.userc{
 border-radius: 3px;
 height:32px;
 margin-top:170px;
}
.light{
 color: #8f98a3 !important;
    font-weight: normal;
 font-size:11px!important;
 
 

}
.username{
 display:inline-block !important;
    line-height: 16px;
     float: left;
 margin-left:5px;
}
.userc:hover{
 background-color:#aaa;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2" id="side-bar">

  <div id="top-bar">
    <a href="#" title="home page" target="_blank">

      <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="">

      <h2 class="title"> Maven Up</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav" id="sidebl">

      <li class="list">
        <a href="Dashboard.html"><img src="images/icons/006-dashboard.png" alt=""> DashBoard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <a href="Entries.html"><img src="images/icons/005-post-it.png" alt=""> Entries</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <a href="globals.html"><img src="images/icons/004-worlwide.png" alt=""> Globals</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <a href="Assets.html"><img src="images/icons/003-picture.png" alt="">Assets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <a href="user.html"><img src="images/icons/002-users.png" alt=""> Users</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/001-settings.png" alt=""> Setting</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="userc">
    <div id="user"><img src="images/user.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="username"> User
      <div class="light">admin</div>
    </div>
    <!---      Navigation Bar User         --->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropup">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle glyphpadingbot" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="gaparowup glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">User stats </a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!---      Navigation Bar End         --->
  </div>
  <!---      userc class div end      --->



</div>
<!-- COL SM 2 END -->
```

Answer (score 0):

[bootsnipp](https://bootsnipp.com/tags/sidebar) has some great examples for that. Take a look at one of those. Most of them you can change to mobile versions so that they are only showing the button on mobile.

Maybe this [guide](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar) helps as well. I really think there are great tutorials out there.